# Grunt slow after couple of hours

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Ever since i reinstalled my computer with a fresh Win8 installation, it seems that grunt (or node?) is slowing down after a couple of hours.

At first it's compiling in ~3s and after a couple hours (in the case of this picture after 5 hours, but it's more like after 2 hours) it slows down to ~30s.

When i restart my computer the problem is gone for a couple of hours again and then it's back.

I can't find anyone else with this problem and can't find a solution. Even 'node -v' takes ~30s. I tried 'npm cache clean' and reinstalling node and sass. And it only slows down sass tasks, not my requireJS tasks for example.

I'm using grunt-contrib-sass - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass.

[a grunt http://gngr.nl/temp/grunt.png](http://gngr.nl/temp/grunt.png)